# How can I create a Link to a Community Page with a lightning component

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components

I've a Community. I use Napili template. I use too nanvigation menu component with new page I created for example "About Us" (/about-us). It  works fine with the menu.
But I want to create a lightning component for example a footer. I can't pointed to /about-us. It doesn't work (Invalid Page)
Here's my code :

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <ul class="myfooter">
    <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>     
</aura:component>
```

How can I have a link to a internal page apart from Navigation menu component.
Thanks for your help

Jeremie

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect the `<"a href ="/about-us">`  to be more like `<"a href ="../about-us">` as that page may be a page up in the hierarchy. In any case, you'll want to verify it's location relative to where it's at in the footer on the pages you're using it with and make appropriate adjustments. It simply may not be pointing to the correct path which is the essence of the message you're receiving.

This may not be related to your issue, but I also know that from the Winter16 Release notes, you want to add `access=”global”` to the inside of `<aura:component>` to make your resource avail for installation outside your org. Whether a community is considered "outside your org" is another matter. I believe that notation is more for ISVs, but you might want to add it just the same.

**Edit**

Knowing that the link was a reference to a single page application would have been helpful. Your link needs to point to the part of your code that calls the "about us" page. Take a look at the [SF1 Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) section on Navigation to see how to call those links to initiate that code. I think you want to be using either `window.location` or `navigateToURL` instead. Which to use would depend on the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you crmprogdev for your answer,
I tried the 2 things but it doesn't work.
I think because it's a Single Page Application and I'm trying with a direct link.
I don't know if there is a event to trigger the menu component.
But thank you for your help Jeremie

Comment: See my edited answer.